# How to programmatically auto connect from Android app to VPN using PPTP protocol (server IP, username and password)

Tags: android, vpn, pptp

It is all described in the title, that's all i want to do, and i have a lot of problem finding solution

So

**How to programmatically auto connect from Android app to VPN using PPTP protocol (server IP, username and password)**